# How to check how many connection pool is being used at this instant?

Tags: database, spring-boot, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I was wondering how to check how many connection pool is being used in this instant? Like I want to find the number of connection pool that is being used in current moment, how to do that? FYI, I am using spring boot and mysql as a db.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring Boot uses Hikari Connection Pool by default. The simplest way to check to pool size is the enable in the logs.

```
logging:
   level:
     com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig: DEBUG
     com.zaxxer.hikari: TRACE
```

It will simply show the pool stats in logs at intervals

```
| HikariPool housekeeper | | DEBUG | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | HikariPool - Pool stats (total=9, active=0, idle=9, waiting=0)

| HikariPool housekeeper | DEBUG | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool | HikariPool - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
```